# Como somar os registos de uma determinada coluna

Tags: php, mysql

Bom, é o seguinte eu tenho a tabela faturacoes, com uma coluna determinada designada por "ganhos".

Cada registo, corresponde a um dia, o que pretendo fazer é um script php, que me some todos os "ganhos" de todos os registos, ou seja de todos os dias.

Como poderei fazer isso?

Obrigado

Comment: você pode fazer pelo SQL... `SUM(ganhos) as ganhos`

Comment: Pretendo fazer por PHP, para me mostrar no painel de adm.

Comment: No link acima tem exemplos de uso do SUM geral, para determinada condição e para agrupamento. Se mesmo assim não for o que procura, pode [edit] a pergunta e acrescentar mais detalhes do seu caso específico para pensarmos em alternativas. Por exemplo, como comentou de fazer em PHP, seria bom colocar o trecho do código que mostra os dados, pois se tiver paginação etc, muda tudo.

Comment: Some as colunas pelo SQL: `SELECT SUM(ganhos) FROM tabela;` e no PHP: `$resultset = mysql_query('SELECT SUM(ganhos) as ganhos FROM tabela'); 
$linha= mysql_fetch_assoc($resultset); 
$soma = $linha['ganhos'];`

Comment: E mesmo em PHP se não for exibir todos os dados na tela, o SUM ainda é o mais prático (é um select igual qualquer outro, você pode pegar no PHP e mostrar na tela) - o SUM só não é vantagem quando a listagem inteirinha vai ser exibida, aí você simplesmente faz um `$total = $total + $row['valor']` dentro do loop

Comment: Já consegui, muito obrigado Marllon, foi com isso mesmo que consegui!

Comment: Obrigado a todos pela ajuda!